# How to switch between hybrid Graphics Intel/nVidia?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus

I have a Samsung NP-QX411. It has two graphics cards, Intel and nVidia. The Intel drivers were quickly found and is fully functional. But nVidia, I have tried installing several drivers in different ways. But I can not run it without success. I do not understand how Ubuntu has by default the switch Hybrid Graphics option. What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

Try ironhide (forked from bumblebee) for simultaneously using the intel and nvidia cards:

#### For ironhide (Ubuntu Natty/Oneiric instructions):

```
sudo apt-get remove bumblebee
```

#### reboot

```
sudo apt-get install dialog
```

#### or

```
sudo apt-get install cdialog
```

#### then

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mj-casalogic/ironhide
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ironhide
```

#### For a WebGL benchmark, install google-chrome or use a

#### WebGL-enabled browser and can try it with/without optirun and

#### report the FPS values on the mailing list:

```
optirun google-chrome http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/aquarium/aquarium.html
# close window
google-chrome http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/aquarium/aquarium.html
```

Comment: Before or after installing the drivers?

Comment: the drivers will be installed automatically by ironhide, as well as acpi_call for switching on/off the card and improve battery life.

Comment: how to know if the hybrid graphics card working?

Comment: try to run some of the webgl examples, I've edited my answer.

Comment: and ubuntu 11.10 ??????????

Answer (score 0):

> https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee **The installation has been**  **updated on 26/04/2013**.

Bumblebee aims to provide support for NVIDIA Optimus laptops for GNU/Linux distributions. Using Bumblebee, you can use your NVIDIA card for rendering graphics which will be displayed using the Intel card.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install bumblebee virtualgl linux-headers-generic
```

Reboot

### Usage

To run your application with the discrete NVIDIA card run in the terminal:

```
optirun [options] <application> [application-parameters]
```

Example:

```
optirun firefox
```

For a list of options for optirun run:

```
optirun --help
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nVidia card is not functioning as a GPU but it surely is ON all the time you are on Ubuntu ( hence, the battery life shown would be half of what it should have been). All the steps can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) . Please make sure you follow the instructions corresponding to your current Ubuntu version.

Once you have Bumblebee up and running, your nVidia card would ALWAYS be off until you use the `optirun` command. Consult the [Bumblebee wiki](http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html) at all times.

This answers your question of switching between the cards.
You might also find [this](http://anantsubramanian.blogspot.in/2013/06/ubuntu-1304-gnome-3-and-bumblebee.html) blog post helpful.