# Intel technology & nvidia Hybrid drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel, hybrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)
>   [Hybrid Graphics Intel/nVidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59489/hybrid-graphics-intel-nvidia)

I have a Samsung laptop (QX510-S01gr) which has 2 graphics cards, an Intel HD graphics one and a nVidia GT420M one. So, the question here is there a hybrid driver for Ubuntu 12.10 or not yet? Also I would like to know if there is a driver supporting Intel turbo boost technology, because when I m running windows 8, the temperature (and the noise) of my laptop is really low due to this technology & the hybrid drivers.

Comment: **also to mention, I cannot shut one graphics card down on bios, there is no such option :/

Comment: The best way is using [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/).