# Bumblebee and Nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I am a Linux newbie having freshly installed Ubuntu for first time. I have Nvidia Geforce GT630M and question about it. I couldn't get Nvidia driver to work. I tried to follow different instructions over the net but it doesn't show in the additional drivers and I coudn't make it run from the console either. Keep in mind the fact that I tried to blacklist the nouveau driver and I don't know if I succeeded. I also couldn't configure the xconfig (I guess that was its name?). So I installed Bumblebee driver. In additional drivers nothing show again but it says now in details/graphics it's Intel Ivybridge Mobile and with some command optirun something in the console(I forgot it sorry) it opens a window that give details about my Nvidia card. So my question is: Is this Bumblebee driver actual substitute for the Nvidia driver giving the PC the same performance as the official driver and if it's not can you give me precise instructions how to get the Nvidia driver to work (how to blacklist nouveau, configure xconfig, install nvidia etc) step by step. I just started learning programming at school and I am a huge Linux enthusiast that is keen on learning. Unfortunately I have no idea how to work with the terminal and how to get this drivers to work (or are they working with Bumblebee??). So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59489/how-to-switch-between-hybrid-graphics-intel-nvidia/296178#296178