# Bumblebee Nvidia Drivesrs

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

Actually I am new to Linux. Currently I using Ubuntu 15.10 on my Lenovo Y50-70 with Nvidia GeForce GTX 860M graphics driver installed. I've installed the required graphics drivers from Additional Drivers. I used

> Using NVIDIA binary driver -version 352.63 from nvidia-352(proprietary, tested)

And its working fine. My question is should I install bumblebee or not?? And what is bumblebee and its actual use. Surfing the net I got it's for linux platform in exchange of proprietary NVIDIA drivers and similar like that. Any insights could be great.

I've already followed these links too but not completely satisfied.

> [Bumblebee and Nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307053/bumblebee-and-nvidia)
>
> [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/is-a-nvidia-geforce-with-optimus-technology-supported-by-ubuntu)
>
> [How to switch between hybrid Graphics Intel/nVidia?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59489/how-to-switch-between-hybrid-graphics-intel-nvidia)

Answer (score 0):

Do not install bumblebee, it provides an outdated solution for NVIDIA graphics chips with Optimus support. You already have a solution for switching between the intel and NVIDIA graphics installed. The package is called nvidia-prime and should have been automatically installed when you installed the proprietary NVIDIA drivers 352 from Ubuntu repositories.
Open NVIDIA X Server Settings (PRIME Profiles) to switch between the graphics adapters.

Answer (score 0):

@Sagaryal I concur with @cl-netbox! If you have installed the official Nvidia drivers, and you can access the NVIDIA X Server Settings menu with PRIME profiles with options for switching between Intel (Power Saving) and NVIDIA (Performance) modes, then use that to switch between your GPUs.

You'll only need the dGPU for applications like CAD, editing high-res videos, or games. When you need that, switch the cards from the NVIDIA X Server Settings, then log out and back in, and you're done. Otherwise, most of the time you will be using the Intel iGPU anyway!

The hassle of using the outdated methodology of bumblebee is not worth it. Especially considering that newer kernels are already addressing the GPU issues out of the box.