# Hybrid Graphics Nvidia and Onboard Intel

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, hybrid, nvidia-prime

I am fairly new to Ubuntu, so excuse if this is a stupid question.

I am trying to get Hybrid Graphics to work. First let me explain my setup.

1. I have a 26" Samsung as my main screen connected to DVI on Nvidia 560Ti.
2. I have 1 19" Acer screen connected to my desktop onboard Graphics DVI for monitoring.
3. Then I have a 42" Proline TV on the HDMI Port of the Nvidia Card.

Ubuntu version 13.10
Nvidia Driver version is 319.60 and also installed prime.

In the Nvidia Settings it picks up all 3 monitors but only display on the intel screen.
I have not made any changes to xorg.conf as I am not sure what to insert.

Is this where my problem is or am I missing something else?

Here is a screenshot of my nvidia settings:
[image: screenshot of my nvidia settings]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Here is a picture of the detection of the three displays. It looks like it is disabled but can't seem to enable it. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71956681/Nvidia1.jpg.png

Answer (score 0):

You seam to have two option:

there is the nvidia proprietary solution

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/using-nvidia-graphics-drivers-with.html

and there is the open driver solution with the bumblebee solution

[How to switch between hybrid Graphics Intel/nVidia?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59489/how-to-switch-between-hybrid-graphics-intel-nvidia)

I am afraid that both require the GPU to be used all the time...