# Blackscreen after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am running into black screen problems after installing nvidia drivers in my notebook. I have a nvidia mobile 540 but everytime I try installing the driver, I boot to a black screen. Only the cursor shows.

My notebook has an intel onboard graphic and the nvidia. Without the drivers, it burns by watching videos.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the latest nvidia drivers seem to help in some cases so please check this link for a step-by-step guide: [Insall Latest Nvidia Drivers for Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/06/how-to-install-nvidia-25635-display.html)

...also...  Check out how to fix and use a dual-graphics setup as well: [Using Dual-Gfx on Ubuntu Fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59489/how-to-switch-between-hybrid-graphics-intel-nvidia)